# gitignore: Are `x` and `**/x` equivalent in semantics and performance?

Tags: git, gitignore

Are `x` and `**/x` equivalent in semantics and performance, in the `.gitignore` files?

What about `/**/x`?

Comment: This seems to be true, according to the [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore). `**` is more useful in other use cases.

Comment: @Dialecticus Indeed, the docs do seem to say that, but when I test it on a repo on my macOS machine, while `/**/x` and `**/x` exclude `x`s in the subdirs, `x` alone does NOT. What gives?

Comment: Surely any performance difference here is going to be inconsequential.  I've got a rather complex .gitignore, and I've never noticed any performance problems.

Comment: @HappyFace: you say `x` alone isn't working as documented: please attach a reproducer to your question, because that would be a Git bug.